# Rails functional test assert_select form input value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing a simple test to check that a form is loading the correct values.

I've looked through the docs and can't seem to find an example that shows how to verify the value of a form input.

I have a form that renders the first_name of a user.

I just want to use `assert_select` on the text input and verify that the first_name field matches what's in the database exactly (e.g users(:one).first_name)

How does one do this in Rails?

Comment: assert_select '#user_username[value=?]', 'starrychloe'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually the `assert_tag` is [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_tag).

There's a good example of how to do this with `assert_select` [in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select), so you could do this:

```
    assert_select '#user_first_name' do
      assert_select "[value=?]", Users.first.first_name
    end
```

Comment: You can combine both statements: assert_select '#user_first_name[value=?]', Users.first.first_name

Comment: and assert_tag is not deprecated as of Rails 4.0: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/TagAssertions.html#method-i-assert_tag

Comment: when i try this : assert_select "img[src=?]", /.+/      then the test is failing. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Checkbox: If you want to assert_select a checked checkbox (in this case 1 checked checkbox), try this:

```
assert_select 'input[type=checkbox][checked]', 1
```

Not 100% related to the question, but more for documentation purpose for others.